# Solr synonyms with space

Tags: solr, lucene, sunspot

My data model:

```
Dress
|-kind
|-color
|-for_season
```

I want to search the model for a specific season as well as for all seasons, like as follows:

Search Query: `all seasons`

Should Match: `Winter, Spring, Summer, Fall`

I have the following line in my synonyms file:

`all\s seasons: winter, spring, summer, fall`

I am doing it query time and I see the solr admin panel analyze page showing the synonyms in the term column. However, when I search for `for_season:all seasons` I don't get any result.

Any idea why? Appreciate your time on this.

**Edit:**

Here's what I found:

1. I had to escape the synonyms appearing on the right hand side, as follows:

   ```
   all news => weather\ forecast, sports, ...
   ```
2. At query time, I had to wrap the query in double quotes. as follows:

   ```
   my_field:"all news"
   ```
3. I had to put the original word on the RHS as it won't find that unless it was repeated.

   ```
   news => news, weather\ forecast, sports, ...
   ```

It looks to be working fine now. Thanks for your time.

Comment: it will help if you can paste your schema for this field here

Answer (score 2):

Space isn't a delimiter in the synonym configuration file. You shouldn't have to escape it.

Per documentation here:
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory

This should just be

```
all seasons => winter, spring, summer, fall
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally there is a problem with multi-term synonyms (e.g. 'all seasons') in Apache Solr. Description of this problem you can find here:

- http://nolanlawson.com/2012/10/31/better-synonym-handling-in-solr/
- http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2012/04/lucenes-tokenstreams-are-actually.html

and here you can find a nice solution of this problem:

https://lucidworks.com/blog/2014/07/12/solution-for-multi-term-synonyms-in-lucenesolr-using-the-auto-phrasing-tokenfilter/